# How does resolution of class member identifiers works in c++

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, inheritance

Say you have a class Ball and in the Ball.h you have

```
class Ball {
public:
    int foo();
};
```

with its Ball.cc file having the function

```
int Ball::foo(){
    return 5;
}
```

and then you have a class BigBall with

```
#include <Ball.h>

class BigBall : public Ball {
public:

};
```

and then in your main you make a BigBall

```
auto bigRed = make_shared<BigBall>():
```

how would you go about using `foo();` on the `bigRed` object?

somthing like

```
Ball::bigRed->foo();
```

but I get told that ball cant be resolved....

Comment: You are using `auto`, `make_shared` but you have no idea what inheritance is? I would advice you to start with a beginner book to learn the basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost. You need to do the resolution on the function identifier, not the object:

```
bigRed->Ball::foo();
```

But unless `BigBall` overloads and hides the original `Ball::foo`, you don't really need to resolve anything:

```
bigRed->foo();
```

Comment: hmm im still getting an error tho, that its an invalid use of Ball::Ball and that method foo could not be resolved

Comment: and your second way states an undefined reference with Ball::foo();

Comment: @sam See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix

Comment: hmmm maybe that's the case i'm pretty new to this and just using the eclipse builder.

but without trying to use inheritance here my program runs fine with about 20 classes in it

Comment: @sam If a class `BigBall` inherits from `Ball`, then `Ball` must be linked into `BigBall`. That's how the c++ object model works.

Comment: ahhhhhhhhh yes your right it works perfectly now thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

With `std::shared_ptr` you can use the `->` operator like this:

```
auto foo = bigRed->foo();
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

All you need is this:

```
BigBall ball;
ball.foo();
```

That creates an object named `ball` of type `BigBall` and calls `foo()`. You don't have to do anything special to call a function that's defined in a base class. Just call it.

That `auto` and `make_shared` stuff is just a distraction for now.